# Android: Knowing when all items in a database have their field set to the same value?

Tags: android, sqlite, contentobserver

I have an app that lets the user select every item in the list and set it as their "favorite". I thought it would be neat if, when all the items are set as favorite, the button switched to "unselect all".

The way I'm thinking about doing this is by registering a ContentObserver, which whenever a change was made checked if all the items are now set as favorite. Then I realized that may not be very efficient. I can't think of any other way, though, so any hints?

How can I know that all the items in the database have one of their fields set to the same value (field favorite = 1, in this case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that should (I believe) "abort fast" if a difference is found.

It avoids the sorting/distinct phase as with select distinct or group by. This approach may very well be slower in some situations and/or only very negligibly faster in others. *SQLite is very darn fast! Also remember that indexes play a good role in RDMBS performance*.

The inner select could be replaced with a literal value which would reduce the complexity. In any case, for amusement.

```
select exists
  (select * from t
   where val != (select val from t limit 1))
```

Comment: +1 For giving a boolean result and although I agree with your comments re: using it in production, I like the idea of avoiding a full index/table scan

Comment: I also like the boolean response. But I don't know that it will "abort fast". It would speed things up to add "limit 1" to the first nested select statement.

Comment: @Ted Hopp I *hope* SQLite is smart enough to do that :) The `exists` should take care so it doesn't actually have to deal with a result-set -- it is essentially just a count(*) that can stop counting if it ever is > 0.

Comment: Good point, but I wouldn't trust that SQLite has such a robust optimization engine. Maybe someone could experiment. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Now I feel kind of dumb :(

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
SELECT FieldName FROM Table GROUP BY FieldName
```

If your result set has more than 1 row, they're not identical

Answer (score 2):

A variant to the answer by Basiclife: `SELECT DISTINCT FieldName FROM Table`